# Insert into 2 tables at the same time c#

Tags: c#, mysql, insert

```
string sql = "Insert into tbl_borrowed (FirstName,LastName,BookName,Category,DateBorrowed,Time,DateToBeReturned) values (@fname,@lname,@bname,@category,@dborrow,@time,@dreturn)";
string sql2= "Insert into tbl_return (FirstName,LastName,BookName,Category,DateBorrowed,Time) values (@fname,@lname,@bname,@category,@dborrow,@time";

MySqlCommand sda = new MySqlCommand("", conn);
sda.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sda.CommandText = sql;
sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtfname.Text);
sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtlname.Text);
sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bname", txtbook.Text);
sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", cmbcategory.Text);
sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dborrow", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", this.time.Text);
sda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dreturn", dateTimePicker2.Value.Date);                   

MessageBox.Show("Item has been added!");
showlv("Select * from tbl_borrowed", lvborrowed);
showlv2("Select * from tbl_return", rb.lvreturn);

txtfname.Clear();
txtlname.Clear();
txtbook.Clear();
cmbcategory.Clear();
dateTimePicker1.ResetText();
dateTimePicker2.ResetText();

try
{
    conn.Open();                        
    sda.CommandText = sql2;
    sda.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ASDF" + ex);
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

I want to insert same values into 2 tables. Im just a beginner, please help me. Bear with me...

**ERROR:**

[image: ERROR]

Comment: You're also missing a ) in the second query: `string sql2= "Insert into tbl_return (FirstNa{SNIP},@dborrow,@time)<-HERE";`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, I already put a ) there, but still the same.

Answer (score 1):

In your `INSERT` query `Time` is a reserved word and needs to be escaped using backtique like below. BTW, both of your `INSERT` statement have the same mistake.

```
Insert into tbl_borrowed (FirstName,LastName,BookName,Category,DateBorrowed,`Time`,DateToBeReturned)
```

Again, instead of executing multiple `INSERT` that way it's much better you wrap those queries in a stored procedure and call that procedure from your code. That's way if you needed you can actually have both the `INSERT` running in the same transaction block by wrapping both of them in a `begin trans` block.